# Yugabyte DB error : Already present: Keyspace 'masterdb' already exists

Tags: yugabytedb

I am using yugabyte-2.0.11.0,I was trying to create one schema named "MasterDB" but it was taking a long time, so I cancelled the request and tried to recreate the same, but it shows the error " Already present: Keyspace "masterdb" already exists".I wanted to drop the schema, but it shows the error "database "masterdb" does not exist"

Comment: an issue similar to this was recently fixed. Can you try with the latest version https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/releases ?

Answer (score 0):

We probably need to dig in and investigate, could you please join our community slack (yugabyte.com/slack) or create an issue on our GitHub? Someone can help you out there.